# How to reproduce this image in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can we reproduce this image in `LaTeX`? I have some idea using

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,backgrounds,matrix,calc,shapes}
```

[image: Imaging]

but so far I can't achieve this, as I am new to `LaTeX`.

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}
    \tikzset{
        module/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=white, minimum size=1em,outer sep=0,inner sep=0},
        mycross/.style={path picture={
            \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);
            \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) --  (path picture bounding box.north east);
            \draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west);
        }}
    }
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{column align/.style 2 args={column #1/.append style={nodes={execute at begin
                        node={\setbox\matrixcellbox=\hbox\bgroup},
                        execute at end
                        node={\egroup\eqmakebox[\tikzmatrixname\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn][#2]{\copy\matrixcellbox}}}}}}
        \matrix[fill=black!20, matrix of nodes, nodes={module,anchor=center}, 
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth
        ]
        {
            Y & Y & Y \\
            Y & Y & |[mycross]|  \\
            Y & Y & Y \\
        };
        \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

**Current result**:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Looks, like you're miles away. 2 suggestion: 1) Have a look into the short intro here and look up more details in the big manual: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . 3) Have a look into the tikz gallery, visit drawings and their code: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/nodes-and-shapes/ (Don't be intimidated: it's easier in the end ...) . 3) Have a look to the right, at the links presented, centered around this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need any of those library. Start from simple node path.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
mynode/.style args={#1/#2/#3/#4/#5}{
#1,
fill=#2,
rounded corners=#5,
minimum height=#3,
minimum width=#4,
font=\sffamily\Large,
},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) [mynode=/gray!15/3cm/18cm/10pt] {};
    \node (b) [mynode={white,right=1cm}/blue/2cm/5.5cm/0pt] at (a.west) {Data File};
    \coordinate (tmp) at (b.east);
    \foreach \word/\col in {Parameter\\file/green,Control\\ File/green!50!black,Password\\File/blue!30,Archive Log\\File/purple}
        \node (tmp) [mynode={white,anchor=west,right=3pt,align=center}/\col/2cm/2.5cm/0pt] at (tmp.east) {\word};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i really wonder can we write a nested loop? how can I go for that memory part.

Comment: @CADENTIC Loop for different size and location nodes is kind of hard, you could draw them individually.